# New User Save Filter

Tags: users, hooks, user-meta, customization

I'm using the new(ish) filter `add_action( 'user_new_form', 'funcy', 9 );` to add custom fields to Create A New User page. I'm then using

```
add_action( 'personal_options_update', 'save_user_meta' );
add_action( 'edit_user_profile_update', 'save_user_meta' );
```

hooks to save my meta on other edit user pages. I've confirmed that when creating a new user WP does not hook into the above. I've tried looking through

1. `/wp-admin/user-new.php`
2. `/wp-adin/user-edit.php`

but nothing stuck out as to how it was saving the new user info. The core of the question is, what can I hook into to save user_meta from the `user_new_form`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this, you have to use `user_register` hook defined on *wp-includes/users.php line 1759*.

- `personal_options_update` hook is called, when an user updating his
  own profile.
- `edit_user_profile_update` is called, when an administrator updating other user profile.
- nothing is called, when an administrator creating a new user.

On `user-new.php` page, new user are created using the `edit_user` function, function ref: (*wp-admin/includes/users.php line 30*)

So, the only option to use `user_register` hook.

Answer (score 0):

It adds field in the New User and Edit User Screens.
Don't forget to include this in your functions.php file.

```
<?php

class UserFieldsClass
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        // This will create a new area in the user edit screen and the add new user screen.
        add_action( 'user_new_form', array( $this, 'show_extra_profile_fields' ) );
        add_action( 'show_user_profile', array( $this, 'show_extra_profile_fields' ) );
        add_action( 'edit_user_profile', array( $this, 'show_extra_profile_fields' ) );

        add_action( 'personal_options_update', array($this, 'save_extra_profile_fields') );
        add_action( 'edit_user_profile_update', array($this, 'save_extra_profile_fields') );
        add_action( 'user_register', array( $this, 'save_extra_profile_fields' ) );
    }

    function show_extra_profile_fields($user)
    { ?>
        <h3>More Information</h3>
        <table class="form-table">
            <tr>
                <th><label for="user_skype">Skype:</label></th>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" name="user_skype" id="user_skype"
                           value="<?php echo esc_attr(get_the_author_meta('user_skype', $user->ID)); ?>"
                           class="regular-text"/><br/>
                    <span class="description">Please enter your Skype username.</span>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    <?php }

    function save_extra_profile_fields( $user_id ) {
        if (!current_user_can('manage_options'))
            return false;

        update_user_meta($user_id, 'user_skype', $_POST['user_skype']);
    }
}

$userFieldsClass = new UserFieldsClass();
```